# How to solve "operator * cannot be applied to java.lang.string"?

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to convert value to decimal such as RM108.00. I have used
  the method `value = String.format("%.2f", curProduct.price);` and it works, 
  but when i want to
  apply `value * ShoppingCartActivity.getProductQuantity(curProduct)`, it says 
  that `operator * cannot applied to java.lang.string`. How do i solve this 
  problem? How should i make the total price into 2 decimal?

```
  item.productPrice = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewTotal);

  value = String.format("%.2f", curProduct.price);

    if (mShowPrice) {
        item.productPrice.setText("Total Price: " +  
  String.valueOf(curProduct.price * 
  ShoppingCartActivity.getProductQuantity(curProduct)));
    } else{
        item.productPrice.setText("RM" + String.valueOf(value));
    }
```

Comment: what does ShoppingCartActivity.getProductQuantity(curProduct) return?

Comment: Isn't your value variable a String?

Comment: You are trying to execute math on strings!!

Answer (score 4):

What this means is that one of the two following methods is a string, not a number:

- `curProduct.price`
- `ShoppingCartActivity.getProductQuantity(curProduct)`

You can convert them to an integer (Or float, if there is a decimal in it) by using the following code:

- `Integer.parseInt(curProduct.price);`
- `Float.parseFloat(curProduct.price);`

It might also be worth looking at where these value are defined, and making sure to use integers/floats whenever possible, as the conversions can take some time. Integers should always be used for whole numbers (If they aren't extremely large), and floats or doubles should be used for decimal numbers. Don't use strings for numbers unless you know exactly what you are doing!

Answer (score 1):

Thats because `String.format()` gives you a formatted `String` and not any other formatted datatype you expect, and you cannot operate arithmetic operators (such as `+`) on Strings. Why don't you try to parse all strings to datatypes by using

- `Double.parseDouble(value)` for `double`
- `Float.parseFloat(value)` for `float`
- `Integer.parseInt(value)` for `int`

and then perform the arithmetic operations.